# When to use aware / conscious / deliberate?

Tags: synonyms

As far as I understood, *aware* and *conscious* are synonyms in which the last one being more formal.Is *deliberate* even more formal or highlighting an aspect I didn't get yet?

Comment: *As far as I understood, aware and conscious are synonyms* There are very, very few true synonyms in English. The guidance is "**If it is a different word, it has a different meaning or, at least, a different nuance.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Aware* and *conscious* can be synonyms *in some contexts*. If you are aware, or conscious, of something, you can tell that it is happening.

*Deliberate* is not at all synonymous with them. If an action is deliberate, you are doing it on purpose.